# Sync data on per user basis

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have an application which connect two different APIs & built on the Codeignitor3 PHP framework. Below is the flow.

1. User register with us.
2. Users add API key for both the API's platform.
3. We sync products & order from one API to other API.

Now the questions are:

1. I need this to be automated, for that I have added a CRON JOB to achieve this & for 1 - 10 users it is working fine.
2. I want to know the best approach to sync data automatically when My application has more than 500 users. Please note that I need to sync data once a hour per each user.
3. There are no Webhooks provided so I need to work with API's only.

I am not able to find a suitable and best approach for this So I am posting here.
Kindly suggest

Answer (score 0):

You must give a try of AWS Lambda Service.